# Cordova, Visual Studio - new project doesnt build

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get running Apache Cordova in VS, but face the following issue. I have VisualStudio 2013 and recently installed Apache Cordova tools for VS. However when I create a new project Blank App (Apache Cordova) and I try to build it, I get the following building Error.

Seems there is some issue with node.js, but I cant seem to be able to figure this one out. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
`
1>------ Build started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>Build started 23. 10. 2016 12:00:25.
1>CompileTypeScript:
1>Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>TrackJsChanges:
1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\file.js;scripts\file.js.map
1>InstallMDATargets:
1>  C:\git\project\mzProject>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.6.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TP1XJFAJ.1OZ\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.76
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.76
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>CleanCordovaDeploy:
1>  Directory "C:\git\project\myProject\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin" doesn't exist. Skipping.
1>MDACleanAfterInstall:
1>  Deleting file "C:\git\project\myProject\\bld\Android\Debug\changeList.json".
1>PrepareForRippleRequirements:
1>  'C:\Users\<Me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.87
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
`
```

Comment: VS2013 owns the "out-of-date" version of Tools for Apache Cordova. Please try create cordova project using VS2015.

Comment: Also try to install latest version of NPM